# Twitter Trending List Printing First Character Instead of First Entry

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I'm having an issue where I can get the Twitter API to provide me with the top 10 list of trending topics in a given area, but I can only get the entirety to print, or the first character to print, but not the first entry in the list.

The following code is what I tried to just print the first entry in the list (entry 0) but I get the first character for each list entry instead (character 0).

```
from twitter import *

access_token = "myaccesstoken"
access_token_secret = "myaccesstokensecret"
consumer_key = "consumerkey"
consumer_secret = "consumersecret"

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))

results = t.trends.place(_id = 2442047)
#I used the Los Angeles WOEID

for location in results:
    for trend in location["trends"]:
        trendlist = trend["name"]
        print trendlist[0]
```

If I just use a simple list like this, I can get Python to just print the first entry:

```
trendlist = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print trendlist[0]
```

Can anyone provide a pointer on why this behavior is different and how to just get one entry to print from the Trending list?

## Thank you!

Comment: try printing the value for `location["trends"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trends api returns something like this:

```
"trends": [
      {
        "events": null,
        "name": "#GanaPuntosSi",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23GanaPuntosSi",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi"
      }...]
```

With your second for loop you iterate through each of the above trend "objects".

```
    trendlist = trend["name"]
```

doesn't get you a list, but the trend name.

```
   print trendlist[0]
```

prints out the first letter of the name.

Just print trend["name"]  and you are done.

Here's a little repl.it for you https://repl.it/BLww/1.  You are printing all 10 because you are looping through them all. If you want to print just the first one, you can do this:

```
for location in results:
    print location["trends"][0]['name']
```

Comment: print trend["name"] gives me the entire list (10 entries). Do you have a suggestion on how to get just one entry?